# How to print First Name and Last Name in a single line in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a project where the First Name and Last Name are stored in different variables, however on querying and retrieving the values, they are displayed separately.

How to join them?

Would appreciate any and all help deeply. This is the last point where I'm stuck at and hence need to correct it.

Also have I implemented the whole page printing using a button correctly below at the end of the code?

Here's the code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Confirmation.aspx.cs" Inherits="Confirmation" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
     <h3>Passenger Info</h3>
    <p>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Passenger_Id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="125px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PNR_Id" HeaderText="PNR" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PNR_Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Nationality" HeaderText="Nationality" SortExpression="Nationality" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalFare" HeaderText="TotalFare" SortExpression="TotalFare" />
            </Fields>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDataByPNR" TypeName="FlightReservationTableAdapters.PassengerTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Passenger_Id" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Nationality" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PNRId" QueryStringField="PNRId" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Nationality" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Passenger_Id" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </p>
    <h3>Flight Info</h3>
    <p>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Flight_Id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Flight_Id" HeaderText="Flight_Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Flight_Id" />--%>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="Number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Origin" HeaderText="Origin" SortExpression="Origin" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Destinetion" HeaderText="Destinetion" SortExpression="Destinetion" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartureDate" HeaderText="DepartureDate" SortExpression="DepartureDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ArrivalDate" HeaderText="ArrivalDate" SortExpression="ArrivalDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartureTime" HeaderText="DepartureTime" SortExpression="DepartureTime" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ArrivalTime" HeaderText="ArrivalTime" SortExpression="ArrivalTime" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Stops" HeaderText="Stops" SortExpression="Stops" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BookingStatus" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="BookingStatus" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fare" HeaderText="Fare" SortExpression="Fare" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDataByPNR" TypeName="FlightReservationTableAdapters.FlightTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Flight_Id" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Origin" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Destinetion" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DepartureDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ArrivalDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DepartureTime" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ArrivalTime" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Stops" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Fare" Type="Decimal" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PNRId" QueryStringField="pnrId" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Origin" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Destinetion" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DepartureDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ArrivalDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DepartureTime" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ArrivalTime" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Stops" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Fare" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Flight_Id" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </p>
     <h3>
         Payment Info</h3>
     <p>
         <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Payment_Id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="125px">
             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
             <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
             <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
             <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" />
             <Fields>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Payment_Id" HeaderText="Payment_Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Payment_Id" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="PNR_Id" HeaderText="PNR_Id" SortExpression="PNR_Id" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="CardType" HeaderText="CardType" SortExpression="CardType" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="CardNumber" HeaderText="CardNumber" SortExpression="CardNumber" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="SecurityCode" HeaderText="SecurityCode" SortExpression="SecurityCode" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpiryDateMonth" HeaderText="ExpiryDateMonth" SortExpression="ExpiryDateMonth" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpiryDateYear" HeaderText="ExpiryDateYear" SortExpression="ExpiryDateYear" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="PaymentStatus" HeaderText="PaymentStatus" SortExpression="PaymentStatus" />
             </Fields>
             <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
             <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
             <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
         </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource3" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDataByPNR" TypeName="FlightReservationTableAdapters.PaymentTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
             <DeleteParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Payment_Id" Type="Int32" />
             </DeleteParameters>
             <InsertParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="PNR_Id" Type="Int32" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="CardType" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="CardNumber" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="SecurityCode" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="ExpiryDateMonth" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="ExpiryDateYear" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="PaymentStatus" Type="String" />
             </InsertParameters>
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PNRId" QueryStringField="pnrId" Type="Int32" />
             </SelectParameters>
             <UpdateParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="PNR_Id" Type="Int32" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="CardType" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="CardNumber" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="SecurityCode" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="ExpiryDateMonth" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="ExpiryDateYear" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="PaymentStatus" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Payment_Id" Type="Int32" />
             </UpdateParameters>
         </asp:ObjectDataSource>

        </p><p>   <h3>
         Card Holder Info</h3>

            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="CardHolder_Id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="125px">
             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
             <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
             <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
             <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" />
             <Fields>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="CardHolder_Id" HeaderText="CardHolder_Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CardHolder_Id" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="IsTraveling" HeaderText="IsTraveling" SortExpression="IsTraveling" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Street" HeaderText="Street" SortExpression="Street" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" SortExpression="PostalCode" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Payment_Id" HeaderText="Payment_Id" SortExpression="Payment_Id" />
             </Fields>
             <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
             <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
             <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
         </asp:DetailsView>
         <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource4" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDataByPNR" TypeName="FlightReservationTableAdapters.CardHolderTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
             <DeleteParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Original_CardHolder_Id" Type="Int32" />
             </DeleteParameters>
             <InsertParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="IsTraveling" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Street" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Payment_Id" Type="Int32" />
             </InsertParameters>
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PNRId" QueryStringField="pnrId" Type="Int32" />
             </SelectParameters>
             <UpdateParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="IsTraveling" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Street" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Payment_Id" Type="Int32" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Original_CardHolder_Id" Type="Int32" />
             </UpdateParameters>
         </asp:ObjectDataSource>

            </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
        <input type=button name=print value="Print" onclick="javascript:window.print()">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is all that code with DetailViews etc absolutley required for us to answer your question? Please just provide the minimum for us solve the problem. With so much code it is hard to decihper which is the problem gridview. Also your printing question should be a sperate question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but this is one way you can show more than one field in a databound control.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("FirstName") Eval("LastName") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I would suggest not using ObjectDataSource in the future because it doesn't really do much that you can't do in code, and it gets in the way when you need custom behavior.

Comment: Your Above Written Code may not work. I Have Checked it.Please Check it from your side. I have also Posted my Solution of the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Func_GetFullName]
(
    @PatID nvarchar(50) = NULL
)
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @PatientName nvarchar(100)

Select @PatientName= (isnull(FName,'')+' '+isnull(MName,'') + ' '+isnull(LName,''))   FROM IE_Patients where PatID = @PatID
RETURN @PatientName
END
```

Call in query where you want to get the name. Using this you will get a single column of the name.

Answer (score 0):

Just Put the following code in your .aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") +" "+ Eval("LastName")%>' ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Try This. this will certainly work accordingly you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")+ "-" + Eval("LastName")%>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: sry i didnt notice that same sort of answer is being answered here already sry !!!